# Can you stop fuel delivery to one cylinder of a 2003 Ford F150 with 5.4L Triton Engine?

Tags: engine

Can you disconnect a wire so gas will not pump into the cylinder?  I have a spark plug blown out and need to get my 2003 F150 5.4 Trition engine home without paying another tow charge.

Comment: I guess another question is:  Assuming you can achieve this, will the engine actually run (well enough to limp home), or will there be other problems?  (Maybe instead of a tow, you should try to get someone to bring you a spark plug, or a ride to the parts store?)

Answer (score 5):

Your engine does have one injector per cylinder (multipoint fuel injection), which is a good start. Some engines have single point injection, in which case you could not selectively cut fuel to a given cylinder.

Unplugging the control wires to a fuel injector will stop the fuel delivery from that injector, as injectors are "normally closed" and require power to their solenoids to open the valve and deliver fuel.

However, from what I've seen the fuel injectors are [pretty well buried](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nONPcU4djiQ) on that particular engine, you'd have to remove quite a few other components in the engine bay to gain access, so I doubt this technique would be worth your while.

Comment: There's a couple that are tough to get to, but if you've got small nimble fingers, it's doable without removing anything.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an image of where the injector sits on the engine and what to look for to see if you can get at it. Since the one in the video which @mac provided is a 2007, this is a picture of one which is for your year (I believe they were the same from 1997-2003). Hopefully it will help you figure out if you can do it or not. Depending on which cylinder it is, you may be in luck. The injector is the yellow thing to the right of the oil cap at the very bottom of the picture (your injector may not be yellow but will be in the same location and basically the same shape ... these may not be stock). If you remove the grey connector, this will effectively shut down your injector. To remove the grey connector, there are two clips on the outside of it. While pushing down slightly on the connector, press in on the two clips at the top. The connector should pull right off after that (this may be a little difficult until you figure out exactly what you're doing). The chrome looking thing which is connected to the top of the injector is the fuel rail (and I'm not talking about the ratchet extension here folks! :D). You can follow this all the way back to find the other three. You should be looking for pretty much the same thing for the other side of the engine.

[image: 2003 Ford Triton V8 Injector Location - From F150forum.com]